# How can I load and deploy a pre-trained AWS Sagemaker XGBoost model on local machine?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I've trained a Sagemaker XGBoost model and downloaded the model.tar.gz file from S3 onto my local machine. How can I load this model for deploying it using flask?

I've tried using pickle to load the unzipped model file but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import sagemaker
import boto3
import os
import pickle

with open('xgboost-model', 'r') as inp:
   cls.model = pkl.load(inp)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 2, in 
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 969: character maps to

Answer (score 8):

Figured it out! The downloaded pre-trained sagemaker model can be extracted from its tar.gz format onto the local machine. Once extracted, open the file in python in byte format and load using pickle.

```
file = open(model_path, 'rb')
xgb_model = pickle.loads(file.read())
```

Then read in the input data to be converted into xgboost DMatrix formatting without any of the independent data or headings to make predictions.

```
data_input = xgb.DMatrix(data.iloc[:, 1:].values)
predictions = xgb_model.predict(data_input)
```

Comment: Thx for sharing, when I do this on a linear learner model, I get: "UnpicklingError: A load persistent id instruction was encountered, but no persistent_load function was specified"

Comment: Ah linear learner models are a zip archive inside the tarball https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=272345

Comment: Is there any way to get a more detailed explanation of what you did here?  I'm trying to do virtually the same thing but have been hitting numerous roadblocks.  The link from @DavidFarrell is dead now, in case that had extra info (AWS Forums have been deprecated).